# Logic for a Convert.ToDbType() method

Tags: c#

I'm writing some "data type sniffing" into my code and it just feels wrong, like there is some obvious feature of C# that I'm forgetting that should allow me to avoid doing statements like this:

```
if(dbType == DbType.String)
    if(Convert.ToString(myVar) == Convert.ToString(myOtherVar))
        doSomethingUseful();
else if(dbType == DbType.Int32)
    if(Convert.ToInt32(myVar) == Convert.ToInt32(myOtherVar))
        doSomethingUseful();
```

(Specifically I'm working with `listBoxes` that sometimes have `Int` values and other times `String` values.)

It seems like there should be a `Convert.ToDbType(myVar, unknownDbType)` feature, or some way to use generics here. I'm looking for a better path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a built-in mapping between `DbType` and `Type` in .NET, but you can roll your own:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<DbType,Type> DbTypeToType =
    new Dictionary<DbType,Type> {
    { DbType.String, typeof(string) }
,   { DbType.Int32, typeof(int) }
,   ... // Add more types as needed
};
```

Now you can do the comparison as follows:

```
var t = DbTypeToType[dbType];
if (Equals(Convert.ChangeType(myVar, t), Convert.ChangeType(myOtherVar, t))) {
    ...
}
```

This solution implies that both `myVar` and `myOtherVar` can be converted to the common type implied by `dbType`, and that all `DbType`s of interest to your program are covered in your `DbTypeToType` table.

Comment: Brilliant, I was not aware of Convert.ChangeType(), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion for using DbType that is an Enum

```
if (dbType.GetType().ToString() == Enum.GetName(typeof(DbType), DbType.String))
            if (Convert.ToString(myVar) == Convert.ToString(myOtherVar))
                doSomethingUseful();
            else if (dbType.GetType().ToString() == Enum.GetName(typeof(DbType), DbType.Int32))
                if (Convert.ToInt32(myVar) == Convert.ToInt32(myOtherVar))
                    doSomethingUseful();
```